# why are both if and else statement getting executed {python}

Tags: python, oop, if-statement

i have mentioned in store class method search to return None if the for loop end and still no return and in main i have written only if its a none then print nothing but it still prints "nothing"
i don't think there is any indentation as pointed out in questions of similar type

```
class book:
    def __init__(self,_id,name,tech,price,auth):
        self._id=_id
        self.name=name
        self.tech=tech
        self.price=price
        self.auth=auth
    
    def _print(self):
        print(self._id)
        print(self.name)
        print(self.tech)
        print(self.price)
        print(self.auth)
    
class store:
    def __init__(self,bookdb,name='abc'):
        self.bookdb=bookdb
        self.name=name
    
    def search(self,b_name,book_list):
        for i in book_list:
            if i.name==b_name:
                return i._print()
        else:
            return None
    def discount(self,tech,book_list):
        amt=0
        for i in book_list:
            if i.tech==tech:
                amt+=i.price
        return amt*(0.9)

if __name__=="__main__":
    t = int(input())
    b_list=[]
    bookdb=dict()
    for i in range(t):
        _id=int(input())
        name=str(input())
        tech=str(input())
        price=int(input())
        auth=str(input())
        b_list.append(book(_id,name,tech,price,auth))
        bookdb[i]=book(_id,name,tech,price,auth)
    
    title=str(input())
    tech=str(input())
    
    store_i=store(bookdb)
    
    if store_i.search(title,b_list)== None:
        print('nothing')
    else:
        store_i.search(title,b_list)
    
    if store_i.discount(tech,b_list)== 0:
        print('0.0')
    else:
        print(store_i.discount(tech,b_list))
```

```
**Input**
```

3
1
TIC
CPP
300
Online
2
CR
JAVA
500
BSwamy
3
BR
JAVA
700
RAJA
TIC
JAVA

**Output**

```
1
TIC
CPP
300
Online
nothing
1080.0
```

**output required**

```
1
TIC
CPP
300
Online
1080.0
```

P.S. bookdb dic doesnt have any use here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **_print()** method in class **book** has no return statement, so python will implicitly return None. Then in the **search** function, when you do **return i._print()**, it returns **None** as well, which is why you see the "nothing" output.

Since you're going to test the result, you might as well make **search()** return a boolean, here's a suggested edit:

```
def search(self,b_name,book_list):
    for i in book_list:
        if i.name==b_name:
            i._print()
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: if store_i.search(title,b_list):
        store_i.search(title,b_list)
    else:
        print('nothing') both are getting printed the one within 'if' and the below one i.e output is getting printed twice once without the 'amt' and once with it

Comment: There are two issues here: first, you're calling the search() function twice, once in the if expression, and once in the else branch, why call it a second time ?

Comment: Second, the search function is doing two things: searching and printing (a side-effect), you should **separate** the two: search() should return a book object if found, or None; and then you should call _print() if search() returned an object.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of things wrong with your code.

- First, if you are going to prompt input from the user, you should provide a message along with the prompt. Something like:

```
...
name=str(input("Enter Book Name: "))
...
```

- Second, `Python` is very sensitive to the (visual) structure of your code (i.e. indentation levels). So for example, the "else" to your "if"s must always sit at the same indentation level.

```
    def search(self,b_name,book_list):
        for i in book_list:
            if i.name==b_name:
                return i._print()
            else:
                return None
```

- Third, looking at this it's obviously not what you want. The `return` statement must come after the `for` loop
- Fourth, returning `i._print()` isn't going to return `i` unless the `_print` function returns `i` as its last statement.

With these remarks, you should try

```
    def search(self,b_name,book_list):
        for i in book_list:
            if i.name==b_name:
                i._print()
                return i
        return None
```

Also, in general

- Try giving your variable names that are descriptive. It was difficult to read and understand your code without using a debugger. You should be able to read it and understand as much as possible what it is doing. So variables like `t` or unobvious abbreviations should be avoided.
- This goes along with prompting the user. If you are going to print things to the console, provide some text to explain what the user is reading. Something like:

```
...
print("Book Name: ", self.name)
...
```

- There is more (Single Responsibility Principle,...), but this is a "okay" start. And you will learn more as you are moving forward.

Comment: well i am practicing for a test, where ever i can i am saving some time, still i will incorporate your suggestions